# How to send JSON data via Parse Push Notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, xcode, parse-platform

I want to send JSON data to Parse Push notification I want to send data like this:

```
{ 
  "action": "android.intent.action.PUSH_STATE", 
  "alert": "welcome", 
   "message": "123123,123,123" 
}
```

I am using following code:

```
 NSDictionary * postDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:  [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"action", @"alert",@"message" nil]
                                                                forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"android.intent.action.PUSH_STATE", @"welcome",@"123123,123,123", nil]];

    NSError * error = nil;
    NSData * jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:postDictionary options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

    [push setMessage:jsonData];
    [push sendPushInBackground];
```

I am getting error that:

Cannot initialize the paramaeter of type NSString* With an `LValue` of type NSData* ___Strong

Comment: I think you have to convert your NSData object to NSString before you can use it. Try "[NSString stringWithUTF8String:[jsonData bytes]]"

Comment: when i use this the text string passed to parse.. and i want json to be sended

Comment: Then I think you should use "setData" instead of "setMessage". Have a look at the documentation: https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFPush.html#//api/name/setData:

Comment: Looks like you're missing a comma in your first `arrayWithObjects:` call, after `@"message"` and before `nil`

Answer (score 0):

The JSON payload is documented in the [REST API Push Notifications guide](https://parse.com/docs/rest#push-sending). The "alert" key should be a string within the "data" hash, not "aps". Also, make sure to pass a string in your "oid" key, if you're not doing so already.

A valid JSON payload would be:

```
{
    "data": {
        "alert": "push_notification_msg",
        "sound": "",
        "cdata": {
            "type": 2,
            "oid": "XXX"
        },
        "action-loc-key": "push_notification_btn",
        "loc-key": "push_notification_msg"
    }
}
```